# Best way to burn ethers and other ethereum tokens?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, tokens

Is it correct that any ethers or tokens sent to the address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 will be destroyed?

Or what is the best way of burning ethers / tokens?

Comment: I keep sending back a spam token and it keeps coming back to my wallet plus 1 ie 232,233,234. Each time I send it it keeps coming back.....how doe I burn this coin or contract drone keep spamming me?

Answer (score 19):

[According to Jeff Wilcke](https://twitter.com/jeffehh/status/872871251366334464), the right way to burn ETH is to create a contract which immediately self destructs and sends to its own address, or just send ether to his deployed contract which does it all for you:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xb69fba56b2e67e7dda61c8aa057886a8d1468575#code

Here's the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Burner {
    uint256 public totalBurned;

    function Purge() public {
        // the caller of purge action receives 0.01% out of the
        // current balance.
        msg.sender.transfer(this.balance / 1000);
        assembly {
            mstore(0, 0x30ff)
            // transfer all funds to a new contract that will selfdestruct
            // and destroy all ether in the process.
            create(balance(address), 30, 2)
            pop
        }
    }

    function Burn() payable {
        totalBurned += msg.value;
    }
}
```

A simpler example without assembly is:

```
contract GetsBurned {

    function () payable {
    }

    function BurnMe () {
        // Selfdestruct and send eth to self, 
        selfdestruct(address(this));
    }
}
```

After calling `BurnMe` on the second example, you'll see that the address of the contract no longer has any balance or code. The ETH just vanishes!

Answer (score 5):

In the case you need to destroy only tokens developed on Ethereum platform, this functionality may be embedded into the smart contract itself:

```
/**
 * @dev Burns a specific amount of tokens.
 * @param _value The amount of token to be burned.
 */
function burn(uint256 _value) public {
    require(_value > 0);
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    // no need to require value <= totalSupply, since that would imply the
    // sender's balance is greater than the totalSupply, which *should* be an assertion failure

    address burner = msg.sender;
    balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
    Burn(burner, _value);
}
```

[Source - OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BurnableToken.sol)

You may want to embed some additional security check like verifying the address of the function caller if you develop your own centralized token.

Answer (score 3):

Any address can work as long you can ensure that is impossible (or, better said, *very improbable*) to find the private key to it.

If for any reason you don't like [0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) as your burning address, you can accomplish the same thing by sending to any address with an obvious pattern, for example: [0x3737373737373737373737373737373737373737](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3737373737373737373737373737373737373737)

Comment: There is no way to verify the private key was actually destroyed