# Ethereum token...*Burn rate*?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, gas, tokens

I'm writing here cos' I would like to post a question.
Is there a way to burn gradually tokens?
I can explain this better.......
I would to launch a cryptocurrency (e.g. 1000000 ether).The feature I want to give to this token is that these 1000000 circulating ether will be automatically and gradually reduced...completely "burnt" (e.g. to 500000 ether). 
Something like the "Ripple transaction burn fee".
Is there a function or whatever other way to do that in the ethereum code....for example I was thinking using "gas"....but I know something like "nothing" about that... 
I'll thank u everyone wants to give his help or his opinion.

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that, but you can implement a fee in each transfer. And instead of keeping for yourself you burn it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [periodically](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time) call a function that burns some ether (or maybe [this](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2890/automated-periodic-function-calling) at some point in the future). To burn ether, you can [send it to an address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16188/best-way-to-burn-ethers-and-other-ethereum-tokens/16190) for which you don't think anyone has the private key for. You can send your ether for burning to this address: 0xd4a0beb031790e5a8c49eeaa188a2e0debae08e7. I don't have the private key for it. Promise! :p

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can dynamically calculate the balance of an account and total supply based on your burning criteria. So if - lets say - you simply want to burn based on time (expressed in the number of blocks passed since t0) you would do something like:

```
uint initialSupply;
uint block0;
private function blocksSinceBlock0() returns (uint) {return block.number - block0;}
function totalSupply() returns (uint) { ... calculate current supply using blockSinceBlock0...}
```

And similarly for balance of an account.