# Burn the rest of the token after airdrop is complete

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, myetherwallet, airdrop

I have started to develop blockchain and learn solidity.

I tried making a smart contract with the 200M supply, the creator only held 50M of the total supply and the rest was in the smart contract for airdrop.

If the airdrop is finished and there are still tokens left there, I plan to burn the remaining tokens on the smart contract.

The question.
How do you burn the remaining airdrop tokens from the smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burning tokens and/or Ethers can be achieved by simply making them forever inaccessible. A common way to do this is to send them to address `0x0` - it's a valid Ethereum address but it's highly likely that nobody has the corresponding private key for the address so the tokens can't be accessed anymore after they are sent to that address.

You can also just implement the burning in the token contract itself by simply making the tokens disappear - reduce your `totalSupply` and remove the same amount of tokens from someone (preferably yourself).

More details about different methods can be found for example here: [Best way to burn ethers and other ethereum tokens?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16188/best-way-to-burn-ethers-and-other-ethereum-tokens)

Comment: Thanks sir for answering, I have tried burning some tokens and succeeded, but what I want to do is to burn the remaining tokens from the smart contract, not the creator holding it. Is this possible?

Comment: It all depends on what functionality your contract supports. You can't do anything which isn't coded into the contract. If you don't own the tokens, you most likely can't burn them.