# Are these BTCQ tokens sent to contract properly locked?

Tags: contract-debugging

In the case of [this contract code](https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xba9350d6d1f14784c84c7d4785fd5533223bd77f), all the tokens [sent](https://etherscan.io/token/0xba9350d6d1f14784c84c7d4785fd5533223bd77f?a=0xba9350d6d1f14784c84c7d4785fd5533223bd77f) to the contract are forever locked? Were they effectively burned?

I don't see any function like the solutions offered in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16188/best-way-to-burn-ethers-and-other-ethereum-tokens), and I can't read the code well enough to tell, hence this question.

Here is the decompiled bytecode:

```
def storage:
  owner is addr at storage 0
  newOwner is addr at storage 1
  symbol is array of uint256 at storage 2
  name is array of uint256 at storage 3
  decimals is uint8 at storage 4
  _totalSupply is uint256 at storage 5
  balanceOf is mapping of uint256 at storage 6
  allowance is mapping of uint256 at storage 7

def name(): # not payable
  return name[0 len name.length]

def decimals(): # not payable
  return decimals

def _totalSupply(): # not payable
  return _totalSupply

def balanceOf(address _owner): # not payable
  return balanceOf[addr(_owner)]

def owner(): # not payable
  return owner

def symbol(): # not payable
  return symbol[0 len symbol.length]

def newOwner(): # not payable
  return newOwner

def allowance(address _owner, address _spender): # not payable
  return allowance[addr(_owner)][addr(_spender)]

#
#  Regular functions
#

def _fallback() payable: # default function
  revert

def totalSupply(): # not payable
  return (_totalSupply - balanceOf[0])

def transferOwnership(address _newOwner): # not payable
  require caller == owner
  newOwner = _newOwner

def safeSub(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  require _b <= _a
  return (_a - _b)

def safeAdd(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  require _a + _b >= _a
  return (_a + _b)

def safeDiv(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  require _b > 0
  require _b
  return (_a / _b)

def safeMul(uint256 _a, uint256 _b): # not payable
  if _a:
      require _a
      require _a * _b / _a == _b
  return (_a * _b)

def acceptOwnership(): # not payable
  require caller == newOwner
  log OwnershipTransferred(
        address previousOwner=owner,
        address newOwner=newOwner)
  owner = newOwner
  newOwner = 0

def approve(address _spender, uint256 _value): # not payable
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] = _value
  log Approval(
        address owner=_value,
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 value=_spender)
  return 1

def transferAnyERC20Token(address _tokenAddress, uint256 _tokens): # not payable
  require caller == owner
  require ext_code.size(_tokenAddress)
  call _tokenAddress.transfer(address to, uint256 value) with:
       gas gas_remaining wei
      args owner, _tokens
  if not ext_call.success:
      revert with ext_call.return_data[0 len return_data.size]
  require return_data.size >= 32
  return bool(ext_call.return_data[0])

def transfer(address _to, uint256 _value): # not payable
  require _value <= balanceOf[caller]
  balanceOf[caller] -= _value
  require balanceOf[addr(_to)] + _value >= balanceOf[addr(_to)]
  balanceOf[addr(_to)] += _value
  log Transfer(
        address from=_value,
        address to=caller,
        uint256 value=_to)
  return 1

def approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _amount, bytes _extraData): # not payable
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] = _amount
  log Approval(
        address owner=_amount,
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 value=_spender)
  require ext_code.size(_spender)
  call _spender.receiveApproval(address from, uint256 value, address token, bytes extraData) with:
       gas gas_remaining wei
      args caller, _amount, addr(this.address), Array(len=_extraData.length, data=_extraData[all])
  if not ext_call.success:
      revert with ext_call.return_data[0 len return_data.size]
  return 1

def transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value): # not payable
  require _value <= balanceOf[addr(_from)]
  balanceOf[addr(_from)] -= _value
  require _value <= allowance[addr(_from)][caller]
  allowance[addr(_from)][caller] -= _value
  require balanceOf[addr(_to)] + _value >= balanceOf[addr(_to)]
  balanceOf[addr(_to)] += _value
  log Transfer(
        address from=_value,
        address to=_from,
        uint256 value=_to)
  return 1
```

Comment: "I can't read the code well enough" - there is no code in that link!!!

Comment: You have to click on 'Decompile bytecode'. There is no direct link.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Please check the help center for how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not locked forever.

The owner can call function `transferAnyERC20Token` to transfer to itself any ERC20 token assigned to the contract.

The function `totalSupply` doesn't account zero address (0x0000..000) towards the total supply, so if you sent tokens to zero address it will consider them as burned.

```
def totalSupply(): # not payable
  return (_totalSupply - balanceOf[0])
```